# Как сравнить что-либо, если операторы сравнения вводятся как строки?

Tags: python, строки, list, input, сравнение

Мне нужно считать из клавиатуры операторы сравнения. Но я не могу понять, как потом взять из списка оператор и сравнить что-либо. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
l =[]
while True:
    s = str(input('Введите(>,<,==,>=,<=): '))
    if not s: break
    l.append(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [`operator` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions), чтобы по знаку оператора соответствующую функцию найти:

```
import operator

op2f = {
    '<': operator.lt, 
    '<=': operator.le, 
    '==': operator.eq, 
    '!=': operator.ne, 
    '>=': operator.ge,
    '>': operator.gt
}
```

Чтобы сравнить a, b числа, используя введённые операторы:

```
a, b = 1, 2
L = [op2f[op](a, b) for op in iter(lambda: input('Введите(>,<,==,>=,<=): '), '')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно через `eval`

```
a, b = 1, 2                                                                     
while True:                                                                     
    s = str(input('Введите(>,<,==,>=,<=): '))                                   
    expr = str(a) + s + str(b)                                                  
    print(expr, eval(expr))
```

Запускаем:

```
Введите(>,<,==,>=,<=): >
1>2 False
Введите(>,<,==,>=,<=): <
1<2 True
Введите(>,<,==,>=,<=): ==
1==2 False
Введите(>,<,==,>=,<=): >=
1>=2 False
Введите(>,<,==,>=,<=): <=
1<=2 True
```

Но способ @jfs более безопасен. В случае `eval` вам на вход могут передать какую угодно команду, и она будет выполнена. Используйте на свой страх и риск.

Comment: Можно проверку добавить, что `set(s) <= set('!<=>')`